# How to get choices value in queryset?

Tags: django, django-models

I know that I can get ForeignKey and ManyToManyField attributes by Blog.objects.values('name', 'entry_*headline'), is there anyway to get choices value in the same way? I mean Blog.objects.values('name', 'choices*_values') rather than using get_FOO_display().

Comment: Did you try to create a model method?

Comment: No I thought there might be builtin way

Comment: I've pondered the very same thing myself. To be honest I don't know why it's not possible to do `foo__bar`.

Answer (score 3):

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    ALL = "ALL"
    NONE = "NONE"
    HALF = "HALF"
    SELECT_CHOICES = (
        (ALL, "100%"),
        (HALF, "50%"),
        (NONE, "0%"),
    )
    select_field = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices = SELECT_CHOICES)

    @property
    def select_ratio(self):
        return self.get_select_field_display()
```

Anywhere:

```
mymodels = MyModel.objects.all()
for entry in mymodels:
    print entry.select_ratio
```

Comment: It's really a nice approach but not what I asked for. anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the display strings are contained in Python, there really isn't a way to have them provided in a database query unless you set it up manually like so:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

Blog.objects.values('name').annotate(
    status_verbose=Case(
        When(status=PENDING, then=Value('Pending')),
        When(status=PUBLISHED, then=Value('Published')),
        default=Value('Draft'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

[Django Docs for Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)